# Asp.net core how can i get current page in View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, viewbag

How can i check out the active sections except for ViewBag.Title

```
<li id="home"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Anasayfa" ? "active" : "")" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Anasayfa</a></li>
<li id="download"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Oyunu İndir" ? "active" : "")" asp-controller="Download" asp-action="Index">Oyunu İndir</a></li>
<li id="mall"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Market" ? "active" : "")" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Store">Market</a></li>
<li id="faq"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Kullanıcı İstatistikleri" ? "active" : "")" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="UserStats">İstatistikler</a></li>
<li id="ranking"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "Sıralama" ? "active" : "")" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Ranking">Sıralama</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a class="@(ViewBag.Title == "İletişim" ? "active" : "")" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Contact">İletişim</a></li>
```

Comment: Hi, if the answer solved your question, please mark it for helping more people. If not, we may be able to continue to explore solutions. Thank you for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 3):

You can check [`ViewContext.RouteData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.viewcontext.viewdata?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
 var controllerName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString();
 var razorPageName = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["page"]?.ToString();
```

Comment: i do it as you said but how can i make these global variable and check them out inside html

Comment: Hi, @byt3Code, did you mean put the code outside not just inside section code? Please detail more codes and using requirements and we could reply u efficiently.

Comment: These are global variable in your section or layout.

Comment: @byt3Code you just put it in `@{}` block on top of the view, if I understood your question correctly, but please describe what do you mean by "global".